# How to use the MEMBER_OF2 function in Oracle Apex using the APEX_LDAP package

Tags: oracle, plsql, active-directory, ldap, oracle-apex

Since I linked our Microsoft Active Directory with my Apex application using LDAP, I am trying to retrieve the groups for the user currently logged in from the Active Directory.

Here's the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_ldap.htm#AEAPI242

Here's my code of **my dynamic action on page load**, I am trying to retrieve a VARCHAR2 of all the groups the current user is part of, and to put it in a display-only field :

```
BEGIN
    :P1_NEW := APEX_LDAP.MEMBER_OF2(
        p_username => v('APP_USER'),
        p_pass => 'mypassword',
        p_auth_base => 'DOMAIN\',
        p_host => 'XX.X.XXX.XX',
        p_port => 389);
END;
```

But when I load my page, this error occurs

> Ajax call returned server error ORA-31202: DBMS_LDAP : Erreur client/serveur LDAP : Invalid credentials. 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563 for Execute PL/SQL Code.

What's wrong in my code ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Thomas

Comment: what version of APEX are you using ? and which version is the database where apex is installed ?

Comment: by the way, I believe the syntax of `p_auth_base` is wrong, because you need to look using an entry in LDIF format. I have configured APEX with LDAP authentication for both password verification + group member the user is of. The link you provided is for apex 5.0, which is a very obsolete version.

Comment: Hi Roberto, I am on Apex v21.1, the Database is : Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

Comment: I agree with you on the p_auth_base, that's what I'm not sure about, I've tried to put ```dc=domain,dc=ch```. But it's not working, still invalid credentials

Comment: if you invoke APEX_LDAP.AUTHENTICATE with the same parameters , does it work ?? can you provide an output of both ??

Comment: I added a new comment with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using wrong the API Package APEX_LDAP. I am doing this on my own enviornment in a different way, but I am using Enterprise Edition:

1. Oracle Database version 19c
2. Oracle Apex version 20.1
3. Oracle Oracle Rest Data Services version 20.4

I have an authentication schema to make the login against the LDAP server of my own company. That authentication schema replaces the default one of Apex Locally managed users.

Application --> Shared Components --> Authentication Schemas --> Custom

```
function fn_val_user_pwd_ldap (
    p_username in varchar2,
    p_password in varchar2
    )
return boolean
is
l_ldap_host  varchar2(100) := 'myldaphost.com';

l_ldap_port  number        := 389 ;
begin 
    if APEX_LDAP.AUTHENTICATE(
      p_username =>p_username,
      p_password =>p_password,
      p_search_base => 'OU=Users,OU=Mycompany,DC=de,DC=com,DC=corp',
      p_host => l_ldap_host,
      p_port => l_ldap_port) 
      then
            dbms_application_info.set_action(null);
            return true;
       else
            apex_util.set_authentication_result(p_code => 110);
            apex_util.set_custom_auth_status(p_status => 'Username or password incorrect.');
            dbms_application_info.set_action(null);
            return false; 
       end if;
end;
```

Then, I have a post auth procedure in the same authentication method to retrieve the groups in LDAP. I prefer this way because it executes after the authentication, but you can do it also with a dynamic action.

```
declare
    l_groups varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    l_groups := APEX_LDAP.MEMBER_OF2(
        p_username => ':APP_USER',
        p_pass => 'mypassword',
        p_auth_base => 'OU=Users,OU=Mycompany,DC=de,DC=com,DC=corp',
        p_host => 'myldaphost.com',
        p_port => 389);
    htp.p('Is Member of:'||l_groups);
END;
```

We don't use SSL to communicate internally with the LDAP Server, as this application is intranet. So the parameter `p_use_ssl` is by default to N.

As I was telling you in the comment section of your own question, I think the parameter p_auth_base refers to the LDIF format of your own LDAP server, not the  domain name that refers to the AD.

**UPDATE**

Let me show you how it works. ( Of course, I hide sensitive information of my own company ). Sometimes it might happen that you can't get the group information as null. I am not sure here whether is a LDAP authorization issue rather than a problem with the APEX package itself

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED ECHO ON 
DECLARE
    is_ok        boolean;
    l_mes        varchar2(2000);
    l_val        varchar2(4000);
    l_ldap_host  varchar2(100) := 'myldapserver.com';
    l_ldap_port  number        := 389 ;
BEGIN
    if APEX_LDAP.AUTHENTICATE(
    p_username =>'X329097',
    p_password =>'********',
    p_search_base => 'OU=Users,OU=Mycompany,DC=****,DC=*****,DC=****,DC=corp',
    p_host => l_ldap_host,
    p_port => l_ldap_port ) 
    then
        is_ok := true;
        l_mes := 'Username and Password Correct' ;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_mes);
    else 
        l_mes := 'Username and Password Invalid' ;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_mes);
    end if;
    if is_ok 
    then 
        l_val := APEX_LDAP.MEMBER_OF2(
            p_username => 'X329097',
            p_pass => '*********',
            p_auth_base => 'OU=Users,OU=Mycompany,DC=****,DC=*****,DC=****,DC=corp',
            p_host => l_ldap_host,
            p_port => l_ldap_port);
        dbms_output.put_line(l_val);    
    end if;
END;
/

Username and Password Correct
SC_APEX_ADMIN:SC_ORACLE_ADMIN

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I tried as you said, and i have "Username and Password Invalid"

Comment: Just in case, here's my ACL that i created ```BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACl_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
    acl => 'ldap',
    description => 'ldap host',
    principal => 'SYSTEM',
    is_grant => TRUE,
    privilege => 'connect'
);
END;

BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
acl => 'ldap',
host => 'xx.x.xxx.xx',
lower_port => 389
);
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
acl => 'ldap',
principal => 'PUBLIC',
is_grant => TRUE,
privilege => 'connect'
);
END;```